# Can R# find all the invocations of a method which pass a value explicitly in a certain default parameter?

Tags: resharper

For example, suppose I have the following method:

```
void f(int x, string y = null)
{ ... }
```

Can R# help me find all the places where `f` is invoked with two explicit parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is available via standard Find Usages, but I can think of at least two alternatives for finding all the places where two explicit parameters are used:

**Delete the second parameter**

if you temporarily delete the second parameter, you'll get a nice list of compilation errors where it attempts to use the 2nd parameter explicitly (turn on Solution-Wide Analysis) to navigate between them.

otherwise (if you can't modify the code for some reason)

**Find it with SSR (Structural Search and Replace)**

Go to **ReSharper - Find - Search with Pattern**, and create the following pattern:

```
$type$.f($args$)
```

where `$type$` is an **Expression Placeholder** (optionally, specify the type that holds the method `f`)
where `$args$` is an **Argument Placeholder** with *Limit minimal number of arguments* set to 2

Then run the search, you should be able to see just the explicit calls:
[image]

Comment: I usually use the first method, but I like the second more for no need to compile the code. I will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly depends on the amount of usages, but for smaller sets, also [Value Tracking](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Code_Analysis__Value_Tracking.html?origin=old_help) helps.

Place the caret on the optional parameter, then use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (default shortcut), then *Value Origin*.

Comment: Also a very nice solution! Love the Value Tracking feature!